# Stuck with JS DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, dom

I am stuck with this simple JS DOM manipulation. 
Following is my HTML markup. I am trying to dynamically generate the individual list items with JS.

My issue: Each individual Span tag should contain an individual item from an array of objects but in my case, one span tag is containing all elements. How can I get it to work? I know this must be something very simple but I have not been able to figure out where am I wrong here?

HTML CODE:

```
<ul class="collection" id="web-book-list">
            <li class="collection-item">
              <span class="flow-text">item 1</span>
              <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"
                ><i class="small material-icons black-text">visibility</i></a
              >
              <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"
                ><i class="small material-icons red-text">delete_forever</i></a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item">
              <span class="flow-text">item 2</span>
              <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"
                ><i class="small material-icons black-text">visibility</i></a
              >
              <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"
                ><i class="small material-icons red-text">delete_forever</i></a
              >
            </li>
        </ul>
```

JS CODE:

```
let bookList = document.getElementById("web-book-list");
  // Create element
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let span = document.createElement("span");
  let linkA = document.createElement("a");
  let linkB = document.createElement("a");
  let visible = document.createElement("i");
  let deleteBtn = document.createElement("i");

  // Add classes to elements
  li.className = "collection-item";
  span.className = "flow-text";
  linkA.className = "secondary-content";
  linkB.className = "secondary-content";
  visible.className = "small material-icons black-text";
  deleteBtn.className = "small material-icons red-text";

  // create text nodes
  visible.appendChild(document.createTextNode("visibility"));
  deleteBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete_forever"));

  linkA.appendChild(visible);
  linkB.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  //Loop through the webBooks

  for (let i = 0; i < webBooks.length; i++) {
    console.log(webBooks[i]);
    span.innerHTML += webBooks[i].name; // Problem is here!

    li.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(linkA);
    li.appendChild(linkB);
    bookList.appendChild(li);
  }
  console.log(bookList);
```

Comment: Just FYI: *"Following is my HTML markdown"* That's "markup." "Markdown" is a different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `+=` and to append use `bookList.appendChild(li.cloneNode(true));`

```js
var bookList = document.getElementById("web-book-list");
  // Create element
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  var span = document.createElement("span");
  var linkA = document.createElement("a");
  var linkB = document.createElement("a");
  var visible = document.createElement("i");
  var deleteBtn = document.createElement("i");

  // Add classes to elements
  li.className = "collection-item";
  span.className = "flow-text";
  linkA.className = "secondary-content";
  linkB.className = "secondary-content";
  linkA.href = "#0";
  linkB.href = "#0";
  visible.className = "small material-icons black-text";
  deleteBtn.className = "small material-icons red-text";

  // create text nodes
  visible.appendChild(document.createTextNode("visibility "));
  deleteBtn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("delete_forever"));

  linkA.appendChild(visible);
  linkB.appendChild(deleteBtn);

  //Loop through the webBooks

  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    span.innerHTML = "test"+i+ " "; // Problem is here!

    li.appendChild(span);
    li.appendChild(linkA);
    li.appendChild(linkB);
    bookList.appendChild(li.cloneNode(true));
  }
```

```html
<ul class="collection" id="web-book-list">
            <li class="collection-item">
              <span class="flow-text">item 1</span>
              <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"
                ><i class="small material-icons black-text">visibility</i></a
              >
              <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"
                ><i class="small material-icons red-text">delete_forever</i></a
              >
            </li>
            <li class="collection-item">
              <span class="flow-text">item 2</span>
              <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"
                ><i class="small material-icons black-text">visibility</i></a
              >
              <a href="#!" class="secondary-content"
                ><i class="small material-icons red-text">delete_forever</i></a
              >
            </li>
        </ul>
```

dont forget the href too

```
linkA.href = "#0";
linkB.href = "#0";
```

Comment: @VisheshThakur if work please click mark as answered, location on left side close to the up and down vote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `span` element for each book in the loop. You also need to create `li`s and links as well. When you use `appendChild` to append an element that's already elsewhere in the document, it gets *moved*, not copied.

Since you're setting classes on the elements and such, the easiest way to create individual ones for each iteration of the loop is to use [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode):

```
let bookList = document.getElementById("web-book-list");
// Create element
let li = document.createElement("li");
let span;                                    // *** No need to create one here
let linkA = document.createElement("a");
let linkB = document.createElement("a");

// ...

for (let i = 0; i < webBooks.length; i++) {
  console.log(webBooks[i]);
  const thisSpan = span.cloneNode(true);     // ***
  thisSpan.innerHTML = webBooks[i].name;     // *** No need for += since we're creating a new span

  const thisLi = li.clone(true);             // ***
  thisLi.appendChild(thisSpan);              // ***
  thisLi.appendChild(linkA.cloneNode(true)); // ***
  thisLi.appendChild(linkB.cloneNode(true)); // ***
  bookList.appendChild(thisLi);              // ***
}
```

I also suggest not treating text as HTML, which you're doing here:

```
thisSpan.innerHTML = webBooks[i].name;
```

If that name has `<` in it (or even malicious script content), it would be a problem to treat it as HTML. Instead:

```
thisSpan.appendChild(document.createTextNode(webBooks[i].name));
```

Comment: Thanks T.J! I was able to solve it by using cloneNode. I tried using `appendChild(document.createTextNode(webBooks[i].name));` but then thought it was not helping so I tried using innerHTML.